# Include Control from top directory

Tags: asp.net

In my C:\ directory I have two folders C:\Twin1 and C:\Twin2

Twin1 contains a folder UserControl, and contains a file myControl1.ascx. So the path would look like this:

```
C:\Twin1\UserControl\myControl1.ascx
```

Twin 2 contains a similar structure but with myControl2.ascx. So the path would look like this:

```
C:\Twin2\UserControl\myControl2.ascx
```

I have an aspx file in Twin1.

```
C:\Twin1\myPage.aspx
```

In myPage.aspx to include myControl1.ascs, I believe all I need to do is:

```
<%@ Register Src = "~/UserControl/myControl1.ascx" TagName = "myTag" TagPrefix = "tp1" %>
```

But I am not sure how to include myControl2 into myPage.aspx

Comment: why do you have that folder structure? are Twin1 and Twin2 different sites?

Comment: Yes. They are different websites/projects.

Comment: you **might** be able to setup a virtual directory in IIS that points to the folder where the UC is. Then just point to that `VD\myControl2.ascx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly (I do not think).

You would need to build `twin2`, and put the `twin2.dll` in the bin directory of `twin1` along with the `mycontrol2.ascx` in the `userControl` directory of `twin1`

You can then add the `mycontrol2.ascx` in the usual way, and the project will reference the `twin2.dll` for the codebehind of that control.

If you then need to make code changes to `twin2`, you will need to open that project, edit and rebuild the dll.

If they're going to be common components between your sites, it could be worth setting up a "userControl" project seperately, and then copying the `.dll` and `.ascx` files as needed.

Edit:
To make controls easier to move around like above, you can look at `serverControls`, where the output is all manually written in the codebehind, this way you only need to include the `.dll` file in the `bin` directory of any other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll need to copy `C:\Twin2\UserControl\myControl2.ascx` to `C:\Twin1\UserControl\myControl2.ascx`

If you want to reuse the user control you'll need to create a control library. Unfortunatelly user controls are not very appropiated to reuse among different projects, although is totally possible.